# Is it possible to stay completely unbiased? What is a good balance between the pursuit of truth and stay happy?

Tags: theology, truth, atheism, creationism

It is scientifically, philosophically and psychologically impossible to prove or disprove the existence of God, as many posts have said. Why not move on and eliminate the possibility of going to hell?

I have adapted this mindset because it is the most beneficial choice for myself, and after I'm in the mindset, I find no flaw in it so far, unlike all the atheistic theories that I believed in, could we conclude that before any reasonable and valid argument forms, this can be considered as the truth?

Comment: because all the atheistic argument that is valid so far solely concerns about the lack of proof of God, but isn't that what u investigate after you adopt the mindset?

Comment: I agree with Descartes when he said: "One should note that what is known by natural reason [...] may serve to prepare infidels to receive the Faith, but *cannot suffice* to enable them to reach heaven. For that it is necessary to believe in Jesus Christ and other revealed matters, and that *depends upon grace*." Rather than being unbiased, the unbeliever is at enmity with God (*Romans* 8:7), and that is not something that is overcome merely by arguments or adopting a mindset. It requires the regenerating power of the Holy Spirit.

Comment: Well you - a priori-  must believe in the existence of hell. the existence of God is not dependent upon the existence of a hell.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda. We should also take into account God's Word as well as the universal evidence of the conscience which bears witness to God's displeasure with sin. Throughout history, the weight of this evidence is reflected in mankind's ongoing attempt to placate the wrath of God. As Charles Hodge wrote: "Every sacrifice for sin, the smoke from every altar, which has been going up through all ages and from every part of the world, are so many attestations to the truth of reason and of Scripture, that there is such an attribute as justice in God, distinct from his benevolence."

Comment: You can disprove the existence of certain types of God, and can similarly prove the existence of certain types of God: it just depends on how you define God. Your "eliminate the possibility of going to hell" is Pascal's Wager, which is known fallacy.

Comment: @barrycarter what kind of fallacy is that? Sorry, I'm new but I didn't use it as a reason to force others to believe. If I'm want to do that there are a lot more better arguments than this.

Comment: @PédeLeão I agree with you, they are biased in their own way, the state of being unbiased is nonexistent, anyone with an opinion is biased.

Comment: @PédeLeão God's word - according to who???

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda. The one true God offers redemption for sins. If your conscience tells you need redemption, you already know which God to seek.  If your conscience tells you nothing, you're probably not seeking God at all.

Comment: Comment removed.

Comment: I would like to see some proof of the first sentence. I believe it is false and that there is no way to prove otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You say...

"It is scientifically, philosophically and psychologically impossible to prove or disprove the existence of God, as many posts have said. Why not move on and eliminate the possibility of going to hell?"

This is a very bold statement and not correct. Some proofs of the non-existence of God are famous and effective. Examples would be Nagarjuna's 'Fundamental Verses on the Middle Way' and (less-formally) Bradley's 'Appearance and Reality'. The whole of existence is reduced by their arguments, including that of God. This is not quite atheism, or this interpretation is not forced on us, but it is a denial of any God we might imagine.

In his comment above Conifold notes crucially that by some definitions of existence God does not exist but is believed to be real even so. This would be the God endorsed by Keith Ward in his 'God: A Guide for the Perplexed' and is the 'classical' Christian view of God. To exist is to 'stand-out' but what would God stand-out from?

In metaphysics it is possible to prove the non-fundamental nature of existence and thus of everything that exists. I think maybe you underestimate the power of logic and analysis.

You may also need to decouple Hell and God. Many atheists believe in Hell (or hell-realms) and many theists do not.

In the end your view is guesswork. You may find it comforting or useful but your reasoning does not get as far as settling the question of God's existence but rather just gives up on it. If you have in mind the most common forms of folk-theism then your argument may have some value but as soon as we move on to a sophisticated concept of God it misses the mark.
     '

Comment: Both hell and God belongs to the metaphysics, and both are concepts that you know nothing of. Does that mean others can't have experience with them? No. Other people could(and there are so many cases) have experiences with things that you never experienced with, and that doesn't make their statements wrong or has to be explained in the known realm. Just like if you've never seen or touched a tiger flatworm, does that mean those organisms don't exist? No, it simply means you have no experience with them therefore you have no right to interpret their experience.

Comment: @Fanger - What makes you think I've had no relevant experience, or that metaphysics does not answer these questions? You seem to be guilty of projection.

Comment: @Fanger The problem with your claim here is that it relies on testimonies of people and their experiences, which are incredibly unreliable. Even if the person giving the testimony is being truthful, an assumption far from justified, it is entirely possible that their "experience" is nothing more than a projection of what they believe they know over what is actually real. Many people of many faiths have claimed to experience a god or other spiritual being, when it must be that if one is real, none of the others are.

Comment: @Dallas Crenshaw - I don't think it's possible to dismiss the entire Wisdom literature so easily. It becomes too difficult to explain the unanimity of reports and their equivalence. Of course, if we choose not to look through the telescope...,

Comment: @PeterJ It's not difficult at all to explain the "unanimity" of such reports. Religion is a moderately well constructed concept, so there's no surprise whatsoever that people of the same faith would believe they are seeing something similar. After all, they believe in the same deity. While some sects of a religion dispute specificities, all believe in the same basic being, and "sightings" usually are very simple. In principle, experiences of deities are quite a lot like sightings of Bigfoot.

Comment: @PeterJ The rule of testimonies: a testimony is only moderately reliable if the falsity of the claim being made is more miraculous than the thing being claimed.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this response answers your question, because I'm not certain I've understood it.

The existence or nonexistence of a thing is a purely scientific question. To assert that it is impossible to prove or disprove the existence of something is absurd with proper reasoning. Take the example of a teapot which orbits Earth but cannot be detected by any means. I can make the conjecture that it is there, and use the flawed reasoning of saying that the teapot absolutely must be real because you cannot prove that it is not real, and one of the main facets of its existence is its property to be undetectable by any means at any time. This does not mean, however, that you cannot prove that it does not exist. While you cannot get concrete and absolute evidence that my teapot is not real, you can say that there is absolutely no reasoning or evidence for such a teapot because of its property to be undetectable.

What I have taken a long-winded approach to saying is that you do not have to use this method to disprove the existence of a god, because the burden of proof does not lie with you. Just as you cannot say that my teapot does not exist, you cannot say that a god which is "mysterious" and undetectable does not exist. You never had to. It was the responsibility of whoever presented the conjecture that the teapot or god existed to prove it to be so.

Comment: You are construing "existence" too narrowly. When we go beyond everyday objects and such it becomes much more equivocal. Do good or beauty exist? does consciousness? does aleph one or energy, for that matter? If they do it is certainly not in the same sense as a teapot, and one can adopt conventions under which they do not exist and are just figures of speech. Those who believe in God often say that he does not exist in the same sense as the material world, so it may turn out that on their conventions about "God" and "exists" God does plausibly exist.

Comment: No, all the atheism theories, primarily based on Darwinism, are incomplete and flawed(If you are against this go look up). A metaphysical being like God that exceeds matter, time and space cannot be proved in this world because it is limited to time matter and space. Also, current science is not sufficient enough to detect all the metaphysical,  does that mean it doesn't exist? No, just because you and other atheists never experienced metaphysical doesn't mean it doesn't exist. In fact, having no experience in this field should limit the weight of your interpretation in this.

Comment: @Fanger - Oddly, I would disagree. A metaphysical substance or phenomenon that transcends time and space can be proved, or at least the necessity for one, as many philosophers have shown, (Parmenides, Zeno, Kant, Nagarjuna, Hegel, Bradley and so forth). The question remains of whether this can rightly be called 'God', As you say this is unanswerable without direct knowledge, but against your view such knowledge is said to be possible by a great many people. ,

Comment: @Conifold Good and beauty are all constructs of the mind. None of them truly exist. We have constructs under which many people can agree on the existence of such qualities, but those are completely subjective. If you want to speak of a god in that sense, then you absolutely have a point. Many people believe there is a god. But that does not answer the scientific question of existence, and I personally would not like to lead my life under the assumption that a figure of speech is an absolute being.

Comment: @Fanger I'd completely disagree, because that entire "argument" falls to the same point I made in my response...you haven't proven there is anything beyond the physical world. You can't just assert that something exists. So your entire premise that God is undetectable because the metaphysical is undetectable is nothing but circular.

Comment: Science may one day discover that there is some complicated physical correlate to good and beauty, we certainly can not decide this a priori from an armchair. And if people can agree on a construct it is not "completely" subjective, many constructs of science are of similar partly conventional nature. As for your personal preference concerning the use of concepts, you can not expect other people to be bound by it.

Comment: @DallasCrenshaw. You assume that God's existence is merely an assumption that people make, but that's not true. God *can* and *does* make Himself known in ways that you don't understand. Faith has its own epistemology. By faith, people have often been willing to die for their beliefs, and I can assure you that they did so in a well informed manner and with an assurance that exceeds the understanding.

Comment: ..."The existence or nonexistence of a thing is a purely scientific question." This looks like a very dangerous philosophical mistake. As stated it is simply false.